# Kafka: Broker may be not available via CLI

Tags: apache-kafka

I have started learning Kafka and facing a issue when i trying to launch a producer via cmd in Windows 10.

Also,i have added localhost details after PLAINTEXT in `server.properties` as
`PLAINTEXT\127.0.01:9092`

```
C:\>kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic Demo
```

Find the error trace below:

```
[2021-03-19 03:10:42,338] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-03-19 03:10:47,433] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Comment: does the server running? add the full server.properties

Comment: You don't need to modify the server properties to run Kafka locally. Error says you didn't start the broker

Comment: Yes both the zookeeper and kafka are running

Comment: @OneCricketeer-Let me check on it